# Calling a function in php with link in html

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to call a function with a link in html. I found the following example:

```
<a href="?runfunction">click to run function!</a>

if(isset($_POST['runfunction'])){

}
```

This works perfectly fine,  the problem is that when I click the link, "?runfunction" keeps standing in my url bar. So when I submit a form on my page it goes totally wrong (it's way to long to upload here). I do some SQL queries and I'm getting weird values in my SQL database. When I type in just my normal url it works fine. So I'm pretty sure that's the problem. I found another example with ajax :

```
$("a").click(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
url: "path/to/controller",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
data: {'mentod':'ExportExcel'},
success: successCallback,
error:failureCallback
});
});
```

I don't fully understand this example (because I never use AJAX) but my php script is included in the html page "include("")". So I can't type in url because it has to be the same page. Can someone give a little bit of info about this, or give an example of how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback method then remove it from the url by `javascript`

```
function successCallback () {
   url = window.location.href;
   window.location = url.replace("runfunction", "");
}
```